# Different sizes of camera preview on Android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-ndk

I'm developing an application that performs image processing on the native side and it receives camera data for each frame from Java side.

The problem is that it takes really lot of time to copy the image from JVM memory to my native one.

Question: is it possible to use different preview sizes, i.e. bigger size to display video frame on the SurfaceView and another smaller one for processing.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you would use the `setPreviewSize()` method of the `Camera.Parameters` class.

Something like this:

```
...
Camera.Parameters mParams = camera.getParameters();
List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = mParams.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
Camera.Size previewSize = previewSizes.get(previewSizes.size()-1);
mParams.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
mParams.setPreviewFrameRate(15); // get 15 preview frames per second
camera.setParameters(mParams);
...
```

Where `camera` is the Camera object displaying the image.

I have this in the `surfaceChanged` method of the SurfaceView. This will change the preview size that you get in the `Camera.PreviewCallback` implementation that captures the camera's YUV image (or bitmap image if you're lucky enough to have a phone that uses it).  It doesn't affect the image that is shown on screen.

Comment: It is actually directly affecting the image size on the screen.

Comment: That example does the smallest possible size the camera supports.  The documentation suggested that it wouldn't affect the preview of the camera itself, only the image gathered.  I've never gone passed the second largest preview size, so I've never fully tested that claim.  You can do experiments with it.  Maybe instead of doing the smallest possible, do `if(previewSizes.size() > 0) previewSizes.get(1)` just so it's only one size down instead of the smallest.